# How to Implement MySQL data into an EJS file to make a Profile Page

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

I am in the middle of a personal project to practice web development better to understand the ins and outs of web development, but I have run into a brick wall. In this personal project, I am creating a profile page. I have successfully linked the MySQL database to my server js file because I can import data to the table, but I am stuck trying to export the data to an ejs file.

I did the following to export the code, but I cannot even call the data because I cannot have SQL locate any entries from login.

```
app.get('profile', function (req, res) {
console.log("Inside Get Profile");
connection.query('SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE PrimaryEmail = ? ', [req.body.email], function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error){
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(error);
    } else if (results.length > 0) {
        console.log("Data From Get Profile")
        console.log(results);
        res.render('profile', { data: results });
    }})});
```

So I did the following in an attempt to resolve my issue, which could work, but I am in the matter of pulling the data into the ejs file.

```
function userProfile(req, res, next){
console.log("Inside userProfile Function");
connection.query('SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE PrimaryEmail = ? ', [req.body.email], function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error){
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(error);
        next();
    } else if (results.length > 0) {
        console.log("Data From userProfile Function");
        console.log(results);
        res.render('profile', { data: results });
        next();
    }})};
```

I would call the function at login after.

```
app.post('/login', userProfile, passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect:'/login-faliure', successRedirect:'/dashboard'}));
```

Any advice on how to get MySQL data to display certain information for the profile page would suffice!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had two app.get(‘profile’) method and now the page loads with no error after removing the un-needed one. The next thing I had to do was add the code below after “results.length > 0” and my data would start to show.

```
user={id:results[0].ID, email:results[0].PrimaryEmail, hash:results[0].EncryptHash, password:results[0].EncryptPassword};
    console.log(user);
    res.render('profile', { data: user})
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've implemented the correct code for passing the parameters to EJS (the first code snippet you showed), so there's no reason something like this wouldn't work.

*Hello, <%=data.name%>!*

This would be because you passed the user data under "data" here:

```
res.render('profile', { data: user });
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! So I tried that and it didn’t work. So keep in mind that the app.get method isn’t functional. I was the function in place of the app.get method which is potentially why the line of code you recommended isn’t working for me?

Comment: @JonD mind adding the error/result in your question? It would add more clarity to what's really going wrong.

Comment: With the way the code is now, I’d get *variable* is undefined. 

For example, it was say data is undefined after the function locates the user.

Comment: @JonD are you sure you have req.body.email set up with every get request to that page? Try logging req.body.email and see what you get.

Comment: I do, it works for the function but not for the app.get method.

Comment: I’m thinking of using setters and getters. When the user logs in, it’ll set a constant variable to the users' email. Getter would return that email to pass it through the app.get(profile) method and see if it’s able to pull data. If it does, then the variable would hopefully be defined on the profile page.

Comment: @JonD https://tryitands.ee/

Comment: Still got the following error message...

    47| </body>
    48| <body>
 >> 49|     <%= data.FirstName %>
    50| </body>
    51| </html>

data is not defined

Comment: Maybe just pass `user` like `res.render('profile', user);`

Comment: Also did not work

Comment: @JonD Don't just say it doesn't work. Try <%=Firstname%> once you've done that.

Comment: That also did not work. I believe the issue is that it is not rendering the profile page. Or it could something so simple that I am not picking up on. I do have one question, I don’t need a route folder do I?

Comment: So a hilarious moment. I found out that I had two app.get(‘profile’) method and now the page loads but the data doesn’t show still but it’s a step closer.  I also would like to thank you for your help and patience throughout this. I am new to web development and kind of self-taught, and your patience is only encouragement to continue pushing forward.

Comment: @JonD I'm glad you solved it! Good luck.